# Panda 3d 1.9 fails to install

Tags: software-installation

i try to install panda3d 1.9 from the debian files

panda3d1.9_1.9.2~xenial_amd64.deb

i download the .deb file . i execute it, the software manager opens but it hangs there nothing else happens.

i am using ubuntu 16.04 Lts on a i3 laptop with nvidia geforce gpu, 4 gb of ram

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions for installing Panda3D on ubuntu

http://www.panda3d.org/download.php?platform=ubuntu&version=1.0.4&runtime

Or alternative on the cli:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line:

```
deb http://archive.panda3d.org/ubuntu xenial main
```

Run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install panda3d-runtime
```